# $_POST is returning null

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting null for all my posted data

below is my script

```
<?php 
require "Constants.php";
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
  die('Unable to connect to database'.mysqli_connect_errno());
}
$ImageData = $_POST['ImageData'];
 $profile_id = $_POST['profile_id'];
  $ImagePath = 'eimg/'.$profile_id.'.jpg';

  echo $ImagePath;
?>
```

in the above code $ImageData as well as $profile_id both are returning null

here is what i m sending

[image]

Comment: Can you show the HTML/Javascript which is calling this page.

Comment: Add the code contains the form

Comment: actually i m using postman for posting my data

Comment: Can you show the headers sent?

Comment: i have uploaded that ,please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding Content-Type as application/x-www-form-urlencoded in request header should solve the issue I guess.

Comment: yes this worked ...but what could be the reason ??why i am getting null in form-data

Comment: When you are sending requests through HTTP protocol, the server might expect a Content-Type header. The Content-Type header allows the server to parse the body properly. For form-data and urlencoded body types, Postman automatically attaches the correct Content-Type header so you don't have to set it. The raw mode header is set when you select the formatting type. If you manually use a Content-Type header, that value takes precedence over what Postman sets.  
Referred From https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests/